# TypeScript Parenthesis Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

Recently my team noticed that the output from compiling TypeScript files under VS 2013 differed from those compiled under VS 2015 in that the self-executing function parentheses style at the end of each function is slightly differently.

The difference looks like this:
[image]

This is annoying because we're constantly having to overwrite each other's changes or else having to revert the changes to all of the TypeScript compiled .js and .js.map files every time one of us builds.

Once our entire team updated to VS 2015, the issue went away, except for one person on our team who still sees these minor changes every time he builds on his machine. We are all running Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 1.8.6.0 installed.

We walked through the options under Project Properties -> TypeScript Build to verify everything is set the same, and they are. We also checked that everything is configured the same in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> TypeScript between the two machines.

The .csproj file is set up with `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`, which obviously is the same between both machines as well.

The only difference we can figure is that the guy who's machine compiles differently exported his VS 2013 settings and imported them into VS 2015, while the rest of us just started fresh with 2015, even though we've verified that all the relevant settings are the same.

Is there some hidden setting or configuration file somewhere that could cause the TypeScript compiler to behave differently that we're missing?

Comment: I think the suggested pattern is to not check in compiled files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TypeScript there is no need to check-in `.js` or `.js.map` files. You also wouldn't want to check-in any typings you install through [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) or [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).

In general, you want to check-in the fewest number of files that will allow someone to run your application. You shouldn't really ever check-in the auto-generated files.

Comment: It's not that simple, it should be the same decision as whether or not to check in the node_modules. There are some articles with pros and cons. The main con is that for now there is no version for typings, and you want to be stable with the version of your js files. And you always want to be able to use them, even if someone messes up the package or even in the scenario if npm is down

Comment: In our case, I'm not sure if the build server is set up to compile the TypeScript files. Plus, they have to be included in the solution or they won't get published, correct? It seems weird to have files that are included in the solution but that you don't check in to your SCM repo. Either way, I'd like to address the root cause, not just work around it.

Comment: @SlavaShp. I believe you can specify commit versions for typings, but I do agree it is not as black-and-white as I stated.

Brad, I cannot give you an answer for your specific issue. In my experience I generally setup the build server to mimic the build process I have locally as closely as possible. This means compiling the TS files.

Comment: @wjohnsto It's true, you can specify versions, but from what I see for now, usually no one does it. It a rare thing to see